# Can we package and publish a website using webdeploy

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment, msbuild, webdeploy

In Visual Studio, is it necessary to convert a website into Web Application project for Web Deploy to work?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using? Note: This is a fair enough question about using MS Deploy/Web Deploy in Visual Studio...once we know what VS is being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to publish a website created in Visual Studio 2010 unless it's a Web Application project.

File based web projects created using `File -> New -> Web Site...` or `Shift+Alt+N` (assuming you haven't changed the keystrokes) can only be published using FrontPage extensions when publishing to `http://www.mysite.com`.

So yes, you need to convert your "web site" project to a "Web Project" to be able to publish using Web Deploy.